# Как сделать iframe с динамической высотой, задаваемой внутренним содержимым самого фрейма

Tags: html, css, iframe

Добрый день. Как известно `iframe` кушает лишь четкие указания `height` в `px`, а нужно что-бы вставляемый `iframe` растягивал родительский элемент, в зависимости от размера содержимого самого `iframe`, т.к. содержимое - динамическое. Кто знает какие решения, простые или сложные (`JS`, `JQ` и т.д.)?

Comment: iframe с того же домена?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    var iframe = $('#ourframe', parent.document.body);
    iframe.height($(document.body).height());
});
</script>
```

---

```
<html>
    <body>
        <iframe id="ourframe"></iframe>
    </body>
</html>
```

Скрипт вставлять в тот документ который загружается в iframe, не забудьте также подключить в этот файл jQuery (проверял на 1.6.2)

Посмотрите еще вот это - http://host.sonspring.com/iframe/

Comment: А без использования jQuery?

Comment: Данный пример не растягивает по высоте содержимого

Answer (score 2):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
   var iframe = $('#ourframe', parent.document.body);
   iframe.height($(document.body).height());
});
</script>
```

Работает, но если содержимое больше высоты монитора, то устанавливается высота которая видна, если бы я открыл этот `Iframe` в отдельном окне.